# Why pip cannot discover my package in sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pythonpath

I have a python environment that has sys.path configured to point to multiple locations:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/shared/conda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/shared/conda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/shared/conda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/shared/venv/torch-cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/shared/conda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

the package 'torch' is installed under one of them:

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.zeros(2,3)
tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> print(torch.__file__)
/home/shared/venv/torch-cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py
```

however, it appears that pip cannot discover it:

```
$ pip list | grep torch
$ pip uninstall torch
WARNING: Skipping torch as it is not installed.
```

What's the cause and how should I fix it?

The installation of pip is also in sys.path but in a different directory comparing to the `torch` package:

```
$ which pip
/home/shared/conda3/bin/pip
```

Comment: Are you activating the virtual environment? Looks like you're using the system pip and not the virtualenv one.

Comment: Of course. Otherwise sys.path won't show torch-cv

Comment: @tribbloid Hmm, how was `torch` installed?